# Search for specific words and replace each with a corresponding different word?

Tags: excel, vba, search, replace

I need to search through a range.
If 5062 is found change to 3201, 5063 to 3202, and 5084 to 3204.

```vb
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Range(Cells(6, 3), Cells(65, 3))

With myRange.Find
    .Execute FindText:="5062", ReplaceWith:="3201"
    .Execute FindText:="5063", ReplaceWith:="3202"
    .Execute FindText:="5084", ReplaceWith:="3204"
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this:

```
Sub ReplaceValues()

    Dim SearchReplaceArray
    Dim I As Long
    Dim RG As Range
    Set RG = Range("A1:O34")
    
    'Array Storage:        <_Array_First_Row__> <___Second_Row_____>
    SearchReplaceArray = [{"5062","5063","5084";"3201","3202","3204"}]
    
    For I = 1 To UBound(SearchReplaceArray, 2)
        RG.Replace _
            What:=SearchReplaceArray(1, I), _
            Replacement:=SearchReplaceArray(2, I), _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            MatchCase:=True
    Next I
            
End Sub
```

Very easy to modify for any number of replacements.
Makes replacements very quickly.

Turns this:
[image: PreReplaceExample]

Into This:
[image: PostReplaceExample]

> > > 

I speed tested it like this... because curiosity:

```
Sub TestSpeed()

    Dim SearchReplaceArray
    Dim I As Long
    Dim Start
    Dim RG As Range
    Set RG = Range("A1:J10000")
    
    Start = Timer
    
    'Array Storage:        <_Array_First_Row__> <___Second_Row_____>
    SearchReplaceArray = [{"5062","5063","5084";"3201","3202","3204"}]
    
    For I = 1 To UBound(SearchReplaceArray, 2)
        RG.Replace _
            What:=SearchReplaceArray(1, I), _
            Replacement:=SearchReplaceArray(2, I), _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            MatchCase:=True
    Next I
    
    Debug.Print "Completed " & RG.Cells.Count & " replacements in " & Timer - Start & " seconds."
            
End Sub
```

Every single cell had one of the three values required to replace.
The debug output was:
`Completed 100000 replacements in 3.027344 seconds.`
`Completed 100000 replacements in 2.976563 seconds.`
`Completed 100000 replacements in 2.996094 seconds.`
`Completed 100000 replacements in 2.976563 seconds.`
`Completed 100000 replacements in 3.070313 seconds.`

Not bad.

Answer (score -1):

I have made a loop which searches the range provided in your question for the given values. If the value is the value of a cell in the range, it is replaced with the intended value. Hope this helps!

```
Sub FindVals()
Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range(Cells(6, 3), Cells(65, 3))
Dim chngVal1 As Integer, chngVal2 As Integer, chngVal3 As Integer
    chngVal1 = 3201
    chngVal2 = 3202
    chngVal3 = 3204
For Each cell In myRange
    If cell.Value = 5062 Then cell.Value = chngVal1
    If cell.Value = 5063 Then cell.Value = chngVal2
    If cell.Value = 5084 Then cell.Value = chngVal3
Next

End Sub
```